# Why does method validation not work with custom Hibernate Validator annotations?

Tags: hibernate-validator

I'm experimenting with Hibernate Validator's method validation.

I've written the simplest EJB I can imagine and annotating the constraints on it.

However, it won't work with my custom annotations.

```
public String checkString(@NotNull @NotBlank @Characters(invalidCharacters = { '1' }) String string);
```

The last annotation checks that a String contains certain characters of a character set (with a default) and is a custom constraint. This works in a normal Validator environment.

However in my test, only the standard annotations work, my custom annotations don't.

```
  this.parameterValidation.checkString(null); // Throws Exception

  this.parameterValidation.checkString(""); // Throws Exception

  this.parameterValidation.checkString("123"); // Does NOT throw Exception - why?
```

I've also tested another custom annotation, and that remains inactive as well.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Here's the code of the custom annotation:

```
/**
 * Checks if a String contains only characters from the given character set. Note that this sets a parameter
 * {@code positions} with a comma-separated list of the positions of invalid characters (based on 1, not 0!).
 */
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Constraint(validatedBy = CharactersCheck.class)
public @interface Characters {
  /**
   * The I18N key of the error message.
   */
  public static final String I18N_KEY = "ipi.msg.validation.characters";

  /**
   * Error message.
   */
  String message() default LEFT_CURLY_BRACKET + I18N_KEY + RIGHT_CURLY_BRACKET;

  /**
   * The associated violation groups.
   */
  Class<?>[] groups() default {};

  /**
   * The payload.
   */
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

  /**
   * The character set to which the text must conform.
   */
  CharacterSet characterSet() default CharacterSet.ISO_8859_15;

  /**
   * Additional characters which must not be found in the text.
   */
  char[] invalidCharacters() default {};

  /**
   * If this is {@code true}, carriage returns and line feeds are allowed in the text, making it a multi-line text.
   */
  boolean carriageReturnAllowed() default false;

  /**
   * Defines several {@link Characters} annotations on the same element.
   */
  @Documented
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
  @interface List {

    /**
     * The {@link Characters} annotations.
     */
    Characters[] value();
  }
}
```

Here's the implementation:

```
public class CharactersCheck implements ConstraintValidator<Characters, CharSequence>, MessageAttributeModifier {

  /**
   * The character set to check.
   */
  private CharacterSet characterSet;

  /**
   * Additional invalid characters.
   */
  private char[] invalidCharacters;

  /**
   * If this is {@code true}, carriage returns and line feeds are allowed in the text, making it a multi-line text.
   */
  private boolean carriageReturnAllowed;

  private SortedSet<Integer> invalidCharacterPositions;

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void initialize(final Characters constraintAnnotation) {
    this.characterSet = constraintAnnotation.characterSet();
    this.carriageReturnAllowed = constraintAnnotation.carriageReturnAllowed();
    if (this.carriageReturnAllowed) {
      this.invalidCharacters = constraintAnnotation.invalidCharacters();
    } else {
      final int invalidCharactersLength = constraintAnnotation.invalidCharacters().length;
      this.invalidCharacters = Arrays.copyOf(constraintAnnotation.invalidCharacters(), invalidCharactersLength + 2);
      this.invalidCharacters[invalidCharactersLength] = '\r';
      this.invalidCharacters[invalidCharactersLength + 1] = '\n';
    }
    this.invalidCharacterPositions = new TreeSet<>();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public boolean isValid(final CharSequence value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (value == null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      setInvalidCharacterPositions(value);
      return this.invalidCharacterPositions.isEmpty();
    }
  }

  private void setInvalidCharacterPositions(final CharSequence value) {
    this.invalidCharacterPositions = CharacterChecker.checkCharacters(String.valueOf(value), this.characterSet,
        this.invalidCharacters);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void modifyAttributes(final Map<String, Object> attributes, final Context context) {
    setInvalidCharacterPositions((CharSequence) context.getValidatedValue());
    if (!this.invalidCharacterPositions.isEmpty()) {
      attributes.put(MessageVariables.POSITIONS, StringUtils.join(this.invalidCharacterPositions, ", "));
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I created a custom message interpolator which lets checks add message variables to the given Map. For this I create a new instance of the check within the message interpolator and call it using this interface:

```
/**
 * Modifies attributes within a validation message.
 */
public interface MessageAttributeModifier {

  /**
   * Modifies the attributes within the validation message.
   * @param attributes The existing attributes, which can be modified; the attributes already contain the values from
   * the annotation and additionally also {@link MessageVariables#VALIDATED_VALUE}
   * @param context The validation context
   */
  public void modifyAttributes(Map<String, Object> attributes, final Context context);
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code of your custom constraint (annotation and validator implementation)?

Comment: Also, is your custom constraint called at all? Or is it completely ignored? Anything in the log files? Which version of Hibernate Validator are you using?

Comment: The custom constraint is completely ignored. I'm using Hibernate Validator 4.2 - and what log files do you mean? If you mean the JBoss server logs: I can find the stack trace of the MethodConstraintViolationException in there, since I log it. But that's only when I use the standard constraints.